# Is this ellipsis kosher? And why?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, expressions, phrase-usage, syntactic-analysis

I stumbled upon a sentence in [something Christopher Hitchens wrote](https://www.thenation.com/article/covenant-death/) eons ago. But I am iffy about its grammaticality.

> And many murderers have been reprieved because they were condemned for the wrong murder, quite probably just **as many as** have been executed for the only murder they did not in fact commit.

I am not sure the use of "as many as" here makes the sentence grammatical, because there isn't a pronoun or noun phrase following the phrase, which seems to be an ellipsis. I thought I'd write the sentence as:

> And many murderers have been reprieved because they were condemned for the wrong murder **;** quite probably just **as many** have been executed for the only murder they did not in fact commit.

or

> And many murderers have been reprieved because they were condemned for the wrong murder, quite probably just **as many as those that** have been executed for the only murder they did not in fact commit.

Am I wrong?

Comment: There is no justification for the semicolon here. A colon or even better a dash would be fine. The comma works. It could be argued that everything after 'murder' is a parenthetical, with the usual punctuation options (single comma, single dash, pair of brackets) (but not zero punctuation in this case) available.

Comment: _As many murderers have been reprieved because they were condemned for the wrong murder, as have been executed for the only murder they did not in fact commit_.

Answer (score 1):

I would interpret the sentence as follows:

> And many murderers have been reprieved because they were condemned for the wrong murder, quite probably just as many [murderers have been reprived because they were condemned for the wrong murder] as have been executed for the only murder they did not in fact commit.

Looking at it, I think some people would say this is a "comma splice", but the question is not about punctuation. The sentence seems grammatical to me with the original wording.